# Saving the language state in different Windows

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

I want the keyboard language to switched by `alt-shift` and saved the state for each window.
OS: `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`, board: `pi 4 (4GB)`

## etc/default/keyboard

```
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
BACKSPACE=guess
```

Comment: Have you added multiple languages to the Pi?  You can do this from `sudo raspi-config` but I think this will affect all windows at the same time.